# Why does the stuff I write in my UItextfields keep disappearing after a few seconds or whenever user hits enter?

Tags: xcode, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, uitextfield

```
import SwiftUI
import iPhoneNumberField
import Firebase
//import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
```

Here I followed a tutorial that mades the state variables like this. But Every time I type something in the text boxes they disappear. And also I trying to push the information into the firebase real-time database. Which I am unable to do because the text keeps disappearing. What is going on with my app?

```
class FormViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @State var firstName = ""
  @State var lastName = ""
  @State var userName = ""
  @State var address = ""
  @State var city = ""
  @State var zipCode = ""
  @State var phone = ""
  @State var country = ""

}

var ref: DatabaseReference!


struct CreateProfile: View {

@StateObject var viewModel = FormViewModel()
@State private var isEditing = false


let ref = Database.database().reference()


var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .long
        return formatter
    }

@State private var birthDate = Date()
@State private var date = Date()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Form {
                //Separates the text into boxes
                Section {
                   TextField("Username", text: $viewModel.userName){ isEditing in
                    self.isEditing = isEditing
                }
                    //TextField("Username", text: $userName)
                }
                
                Section {
                    TextField("First Name", text: $viewModel.firstName)
                    TextField("Last  Name", text: $viewModel.lastName)
                    
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Enter Birthday")) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Enter your birthday")
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        DatePicker("Enter your birthday", selection: $date)
                                        .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                                        .frame(maxHeight: 400)
                    }
                    
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Enter your Mailing Address")) {
                    TextField("Street Address", text: $viewModel.address)
                    TextField("City", text: $viewModel.city)
                    TextField("Postal Code", text: $viewModel.zipCode)
                    TextField("Country", text: $viewModel.country)
                    
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Phone Number")) {
                    iPhoneNumberField(text: $viewModel.phone)
                                .flagHidden(false)
                                .flagSelectable(true)
                    
                    
                        }
                }.navigationTitle("Create Account")
                Divider()
                Button(action: {
                    //Push Data to firebase database here
                    
                    ref.childByAutoId().setValue(["User": $viewModel.userName,"First Name": $viewModel.firstName, "Last Name": $viewModel.lastName,"Last Name": $viewModel.lastName,"Address": $viewModel.address,"City": $viewModel.city,"Zipcode": $viewModel.zipCode,
                        "Country":
                            $viewModel.country,
                        "Phone":$viewModel.phone
                    ])
                    
                }, label: {
                    
                    Text("Save Profile")
                        .frame(width: 250,
                               height: 50,
                               alignment: .center)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        
                })
                .padding()
                
            }
        }
        //This is the create account title
        
    //.textColor(.black)
    }
}

struct CreateProfile_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    CreateProfile()
        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like Firestore is being imported incorrectly. I have viewed many tutorials and none of them import Firestore in that manner, even if you un-comment it.

I would watch Waga Odongo's Instagram clone videos on Youtube. They cover this sort of thing and have helped me to make working TextFields.